# Unable to interact with public sections of my website but able to interact with private sections when I add a $uid firebase rule

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using Realtime Database NOT firestore. I have a Firebase rule which I’ve tested and works below.

```
        "$uid": {     
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (!data.exists() || data.child('user').child('uid').val() === auth.uid)",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (!data.exists() || auth.uid === $uid)"      }
    },
```

I then copied this rule to all collections of my data to see what would happen to my website. See copy of my rules. **Note:** I have had to remove the rule entirely for some of the collections. Read further for full details.

```
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
      ".indexOn": "username",
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true"                  
    },
     "tariffs":{
        "$uid": {     
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (!data.exists() || data.child('user').child('uid').val() === auth.uid)",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (!data.exists() || auth.uid === $uid)"      }
    },
    "benefitQuestionData":{
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true" 
    },
    "newFeatureRequests": {
      "$uid": {     
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (!data.exists() || data.child('user').child('uid').val() === auth.uid)",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (!data.exists() || auth.uid === $uid)"      }
    },
    "experiencesSharedByUsers": {
      ".indexOn": "benefitTitle",
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true"
    },
    "reportedExperiences": {
      "$uid": {     
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (!data.exists() || data.child('user').child('uid').val() === auth.uid)",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (!data.exists() || auth.uid === $uid)"      }

    },
    "activeUsers": {
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true"
    },
    "deletedAccounts": {
    ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    },
  }
}
```

**Problem**
For the collections where data goes to the backend without being displayed publicly I don’t have any issues with the website. For reference these are the collections tariffs, newFeatureRequests and reportedExperiences from the code above.

However for the collections where data is displayed publicly (e.g. user posts) then I start to see issues with the website. For example I wont be able to see other user posts or the website content wont display properly. For reference these are the remaining collections in the code above.

As mentioned above to enable the website to work I've had to relax the strictness of the rules for some collections to the below:

```
 ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
 ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true"
```

For troubleshooting purposes I have copied the Angular backend code below in case it provides some clues. The remaining code (not displayed here) is just the html and css for styling.

**1.    Backend code from request feature (collection where data is not displayed publicly)**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LayoutComponent } from '../layout/layout.component';
import { ContentContainerComponent } from '../content-container/content-container.component';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  UntypedFormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { NewFeatureRequestPayload } from '../../types/types';
import { RequestFeatureService } from '../../services/request-feature.service';
import { UserAuthData } from '../../types/user-types';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { ShadowBannedService } from '../../services/shadow-banned.service';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-request-feature',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LayoutComponent,
    ContentContainerComponent,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterLink,
  ],
  templateUrl: './request-feature.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./request-feature.component.scss'],
})
export class RequestFeatureComponent implements OnInit {
  public requestFeatureForm: UntypedFormGroup;
  public isRequestFeatureFormSubmitted = false;

  public isRequestSubmittedSuccessfully = false;
  public isSubmissionInProgress = false;

  public disableSubmitButton: boolean = true;
  public username: string;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private requestFeatureService: RequestFeatureService,
    private shadowBannedService: ShadowBannedService,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.username =
      this.userService.getUserDataFromLocalStorage().userInfo.username;

    this.requestFeatureForm = this.fb.group({
      newFeatureDescription: ['', [Validators.required]],
      isCurrentWebSiteAnnoying: ['', [Validators.required]],
      reason: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });

    this.requestFeatureService
      .getAllNewFeatureRequests()
      .then((data) => {
        const filteredData = data
          .filter((item) => item.username === this.username)
          .filter((item) => dayjs(item.date).isSame(new Date(), 'day'));

        this.disableSubmitButton = !!filteredData.length;
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }

  public onSubmit(): void {
    this.isRequestFeatureFormSubmitted = true;
    if (!this.requestFeatureForm.valid) {
      return;
    }

    const user: UserAuthData = this.userService.getUserDataFromLocalStorage();
    const currentDate: string = dayjs(new Date()).format('MMM D, YYYY h:mm A');

    if (user.userInfo?.uid && user.userInfo.username) {
      const payload: NewFeatureRequestPayload = {
        uid: uuidv4(),
        userId: user.userInfo?.uid,
        username: user.userInfo?.username,
        newFeatureDescription:
          this.requestFeatureForm.value.newFeatureDescription,
        isCurrentWebSiteAnnoying:
          this.requestFeatureForm.value.isCurrentWebSiteAnnoying,
        reason: this.requestFeatureForm.value.reason,
        date: currentDate,
      };

      this.isSubmissionInProgress = true;

      this.requestFeatureService
        .doesRequestFeatureContainBannedWords(payload)
        .then((doesExperienceContainBannedWords) => {
          if (doesExperienceContainBannedWords && user.userInfo?.uid) {
            this.shadowBannedService.setUserStatusAsShadowedBanned(
              user.userInfo.uid,
            );

            this.requestFeatureService
              .saveNewFeatureRequestForBannedUsers(payload)
              .then(() => {
                this.isRequestSubmittedSuccessfully = true;
                this.isSubmissionInProgress = false;
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
              });
          } else {
            this.requestFeatureService
              .saveNewFeatureRequestForNormalUsers(payload)
              .then(() => {
                this.isRequestSubmittedSuccessfully = true;
                this.isSubmissionInProgress = false;
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
              });
          }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

**2.    Backend code from experiencessharedbyusers (collection where data is displayed publicly)**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  UntypedFormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { UserAuthData } from '../../types/user-types';
import { OjasPointsOperation, ShareExperiencePayload } from '../../types/types';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { take } from 'rxjs';
import { Benefit } from '../../../home/category-benefits/category-benefits.service';
import { ShareExperienceService } from '../../services/share-experience.service';
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { OjasPointsService } from '../../services/ojas-points.service';
import { ShadowBannedService } from '../../services/shadow-banned.service';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-share-experience',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterLink],
  templateUrl: './share-experience.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./share-experience.component.scss'],
})
export class ShareExperienceComponent implements OnInit {
  public benefit: Benefit;
  public shareExperienceForm: UntypedFormGroup;
  public isFormSubmitted = false;

  public isFormSubmittedSuccessfully = false;
  public isSubmissionInProgress = false;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private shareExperienceService: ShareExperienceService,
    private ojasPointsService: OjasPointsService,
    private shadowBannedService: ShadowBannedService,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shareExperienceForm = this.fb.group({
      title: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(20),
          Validators.maxLength(150),
        ],
      ],
      experienceDescription: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(100),
          Validators.maxLength(5000),
        ],
      ],
      otherInsights: [
        '',
        [Validators.minLength(0), Validators.maxLength(5000)],
      ],
    });

    this.activatedRoute.data.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((data) => {
      if (!data['benefit']) {
        this.router.navigate(['oops']);
        return;
      }
      this.benefit = data['benefit'];
    });
  }

  public async onSubmit(): Promise<void> {
    this.isFormSubmitted = true;
    if (!this.shareExperienceForm.valid) {
      return;
    }

    const user: UserAuthData = this.userService.getUserDataFromLocalStorage();
    this.isSubmissionInProgress = true;

    if (
      user.userInfo?.uid &&
      user.userInfo?.username &&
      user.userInfo?.userTribe
    ) {
      await this.ojasPointsService.UpdateOjasPoints({
        userUid: user.userInfo.uid,
        operation: OjasPointsOperation.increment,
        amount: 2,
      });

      const currentDate: string = dayjs(new Date()).format(
        'MMM D, YYYY h:mm A',
      );

      const payload: ShareExperiencePayload = {
        uid: uuidv4(),
        userId: user.userInfo?.uid,
        username: user.userInfo?.username,
        userTribe: user.userInfo?.userTribe,

        benefitTitle: this.benefit.title,
        categoryByDays: this.benefit.categoryByDays,

        experienceTitle: this.shareExperienceForm.value.title,
        experienceDescription:
          this.shareExperienceForm.value.experienceDescription,
        experienceInsights: this.shareExperienceForm.value.otherInsights,

        date: currentDate,
        voteCounter: 0,

        usersListWhoLikedTheExperience: ['*'],
        usersListWhoDislikedTheExperience: ['*'],
      };

      this.isSubmissionInProgress = true;

      this.shareExperienceService
        .doesExperienceContainBannedWords(payload)
        .then((doesExperienceContainBannedWords) => {
          if (doesExperienceContainBannedWords && user.userInfo?.uid) {
            this.shadowBannedService.setUserStatusAsShadowedBanned(
              user.userInfo.uid,
            );
          }
        });

      this.shareExperienceService
        .shareExperienceRequest(payload)
        .then(() => {
          this.router.navigate([
            `/benefits/${this.benefit.title}/${this.benefit.categoryByDays}`,
          ]);
          this.isFormSubmittedSuccessfully = true;
          this.isSubmissionInProgress = false;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          this.isSubmissionInProgress = false;
        });
    }
  }
}
```

I would appreciate some help in guiding me to possible ideas for the discrepancy.

Thanks

Comment: There's a lot of code in your question. Can you point which specific read or write operation is not working. I also recommend checking out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there drastically increases the chances that someone can help.

Comment: Hi @Frank van Puffelen. Thanks for your response as always. I dont know which specific part of the backend code is causing the website to not display correctly. In the meantime I am going to read that guide you've posted and see how I can better formulate the question. Unfortunately I am not a software engineer, I am an entrepeneur who hired a software engineer to build the site for me. So it will take me a few weeks-months to understand the link you've sent and be able to produce something that is verifiable(Doing all this outside my normal 9-5 job)